# Сформировать XML-документ с кириллическми тегами

Tags: php, xml

Формирую XML документ:

```php
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="windows-1251"?>
<doc>
</doc>
XML;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но теги прописанные кириллическими символами как тэги не воспринимаются.

```php
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="windows-1251"?>
<док>
</док>
XML;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а если кодировку делать `UTF-8`?  https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-non-eng-tags - "n XML it is possible to define your own tag names. You can do this in any language and script supported by **Unicode**."

Comment: Еще хотелось бы, чисто для себя, узнать, что является поводом использовать теги на русском?

Comment: Для обмена с 1С.`UTF-8` ставил - не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так))

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");
echo $xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="utf-8"?>
<док>
</док>
XML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Установить перед выводом

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=windows-1251");
```